# Create a Multi-Index pandas df by multiplying a df by N number of constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df:

```
dates         p1     p2    p3    p4    
2019-12-01   0.4    0.4   0.4   0.3 
2019-12-02   0.41   0.3   0.3   0.3
```

And a constants df like this:

```
   v1      v2      v3
0   43  0.680068  680.068
1  210  0.319932  319.932
2  211  0.319932  319.932
```

I would like to multiply each element in the first df by each value of `v3` and create a multi-index which takes the v1 as the top-level index - something that looks like this:

```
                                 43                                 210  ...
dates            p1             p2         p3         p4       ...   p1 ...
2019-12-01   0.4 * 680.068    0.4* v3    0.4 * v3   0.3 * v3   ...  0.3 * 319.932 
2019-12-02   0.41 * v3   0.3 * v3   0.3 * v3  0.3 * v3   ...   ...  ...
```

So this would result in 1 df with 3 top-level indexes (43, 210, 211) and then to lower level will be 3 dfs that have had element-by-element multiplication

Comment: So what happens to v1 and v2 column values??

Comment: V1 will be used to lookup, v2 isn't actually used, so I omit it from the original df

Comment: do you mean you want a cartesian multiplication of each cell and the v3 series? also can v1 have duplicate values?

Comment: Yes cartesian multiplication and no, v1 will always be unique

Comment: @anky_91 just realised my question was wrong and edited it - for the multi-index it would be each value of v1 as the top index - please see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple extension of your previous question. I will still assume that `dates` is used as the index for the initial dataframe, say `df`:

```
              p1   p2   p3   p4
dates                          
2019-12-01  0.40  0.4  0.4  0.3
2019-12-02  0.41  0.3  0.3  0.3
```

Let us call `v` the second dataframe, and `dg` the result.

We can simply compute the values with `concat`:

```
dg = pd.concat([df * val for val in v['v3']], axis = 1)
```

Then, we compute the columns label with `MultiIndex.from_products`:

```
dg.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([v['v1'], df.columns])
```

to obtain:

```
                  43                                       210                                     211                             
                   p1        p2        p3        p4         p1        p2        p3       p4         p1        p2        p3       p4
dates                                                                                                                              
2019-12-01  272.02720  272.0272  272.0272  204.0204  127.97280  127.9728  127.9728  95.9796  127.97280  127.9728  127.9728  95.9796
2019-12-02  278.82788  204.0204  204.0204  204.0204  131.17212   95.9796   95.9796  95.9796  131.17212   95.9796   95.9796  95.9796
```

---

It can even be done in one single pass (thank to anky_91 for the trick):

```
pd.concat([df * val for val in v['v3']], axis = 1,keys=v['v1'])
```

---

A multiindex can have names, so you can even do:

```
dg.columns.names=('v1', '')
```

to get:

```
v1                43                                       210                                     211                             
                   p1        p2        p3        p4         p1        p2        p3       p4         p1        p2        p3       p4
dates                                                                                                                              
2019-12-01  272.02720  272.0272  272.0272  204.0204  127.97280  127.9728  127.9728  95.9796  127.97280  127.9728  127.9728  95.9796
2019-12-02  278.82788  204.0204  204.0204  204.0204  131.17212   95.9796   95.9796  95.9796  131.17212   95.9796   95.9796  95.9796
```

Comment: nice one , i thought too complex, bdw you can add keys directly in concat too for the multiindex : `pd.concat([df1 * val for val in df2['v3']], axis = 1,keys=df2['v1'])` :) +1

Comment: @anky_91: thank you for the advice, I had never used that syntax, and I have edited my post with it.